# java.io.Exception Unexpected End Of Stream on com.android.okhttp

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, android-studio, amazon-ec2, okhttp

I'm currently working on Android Studio. Just trying to make an app to register account and save data on database using LAMP stack.

The code I was using worked for localhost (I'm using XAMPP), it posted data to the database.

Howevers, when I change the URL to my EC2 machine on AWS, the app showing "java.io.Exception Unexpected End Of Stream on com.android.okhttp" and didn't post data to database. I tested and verify the URL is correct.

What else should I try for this problem ? Any help would be really appreciated !

**Here is the app UI**: 
[Click to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xt8Eu.png)

**Here is the code:**

---

```
package com.example.androidphp;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private EditText editTextUserName, editTextEmail, editTextPassword;
    private Button buttonRegister;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        editTextEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
        editTextUserName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextUserName);
        editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);
        buttonRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonRegister);

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        buttonRegister.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    private void registerUser(){
        final String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();
        final String username = editTextUserName.getText().toString().trim();
        final String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();

        progressDialog.setMessage("Registering User....");
        progressDialog.show();

        // class from volley
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                Constants.URL_REGISTER,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), jsonObject.getString("message"),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        progressDialog.hide();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("username", username);
                params.put("email", email);
                params.put("password", password);
                return params;
            }
        };
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v == buttonRegister)
            registerUser();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem to my device with android 10, if your protocol url is `http`, you must add `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` in manifest.

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

</Application>
```

in android 9 pi [API Level 28] and later you must set a `networkSecurityConfig` in your Manifest application tag like this:

```
 <application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config">
```

then in your xml folder create your xml file and should be like this to enable all requests without encryptions:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="false">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">secure.example.com</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

plz see this links for more information: [Read 1](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config) -- [Read 2](https://medium.com/@imstudio/android-8-cleartext-http-traffic-not-permitted-73c1c9e3b803)