# API crashing due to Unexpected end of stream on com.android.okhttp.Address

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, okhttp, dotnet-httpclient

I developed a mobile app and an ASP.Net Core Web API for a project we have in our enterprise. When I try to run the app accessing my API, it crashes. In debug, I keep getting this exception (sometimes the number at the end changes, but I don't know what it means):

> System.Exception: 'unexpected end of stream on com.android.okhttp.Address@91704093'

A friend recommended me to run the app while running `dotnet MyAPI.dll --urls "http://*:myportnumber` command on cmd in our API server. Here's the result:

```
dotnet MyAPI.dll --urls "http://*:myportnumber"
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Now listening on: http://[::]:myportnumber
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Production
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: C:\IISsites\MyAPIFolder
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy.HttpsRedirectionMiddleware[3]
      Failed to determine the https port for redirect.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application is shutting down...
```

There is this small warning, which I removed by following [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53724391/11417475), but then the API access on the app began to take forever to load, so I decided to just ignore the warning.

While this command is in execution on the server, the API works like a charm on the app, but when I stop running it, the exception returns or the app crashes.

In order to solve the exception, I have tried to:

1. ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61610493/11417475)) Add `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"` to the app's `AndroidManifest.xml` and create a new xml file in `Resources\xml\network_security_config.xml` with the following code:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="false">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">https://ourenterpriseurl.com.br/api</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

2. ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55397298/11417475)) Set the HttpClient implementation to Android and the SSL/TLS implementation to Native TLS1.2+ on Project Options > Android Options > Advanced Options;
3. ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/web-host?view=aspnetcore-6.0#override-configuration)) Edit the `CreateHostBuilder` method on `Program.cs` like this:

```cs
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
{
    var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddJsonFile("hostsettings.json", optional: true)
        .AddCommandLine(args)
        .Build();

    return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseConfiguration(config)
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseUrls("http://*:myportnumber")
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
        });
}
```

The content of `hostsettings.json` is:

```json
{
  "urls": "http://*:myportnumber"
}
```

**So, how do I get rid of this exception in order to make my project work?**

---

ABOUT THE API: it is developed in ASP.Net Core 5.0; accesses stored procedures in our SQL Server database with it's own SQL credentials; it is published on the IIS of an OnPremises server of ours; it becomes publicly available for our mobile app via FortiWeb; the connection string is encrypted using `Aes` and `CryptoStream` and the resulting string is written in `appsettings.json`; the connection string is decrypted in `Startup.cs`.

Comment: How long does it take for error message to occur?  Is it immediate, 30 seconds, or different time?  Does it always fail at same time? Does it happen with all data or only some data?  I'm guessing but thinking the command to database is taking more than 30 seconds and need to change the command timeout.

Comment: It is immediate! The first API method to be called is a POST method, and as I send the request, the exception happens... it is not a timeout

Comment: Do search for "failed to determine the https port for redirect". 
 Here is one result : https://www.thecodebuzz.com/failed-to-determine-the-https-port-for-the-redirect/?force_isolation=true

Comment: I tried both solutions presented on the article, none worked :/ as far as I know, our publication server already handles https redirection... I guess

Comment: Did you search web for other solutions?  Have seen issues where connection to proxy server was using https and connection to URL was using http, or proxy was using http and URL was using https. Port 443 is TLS for https.  Port 80 or 8080 is http.  If you are behind a firewall you may be using port 80ot 8080 to proxy.  Maybe using port 80 or 8080 instead of 443 will solve issue.

Comment: On my API I pass the url with https and our server is also using https... we have a firewall and the API is not using 443, our security specialist guaranteed it to me

Comment: Show your expert the following : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers?force_isolation=true.  TLS is automatic when HTTPS is used and defaults to port 443 for TLS.  Check event logs on the server to see if there are any error messages.

Comment: Well the port we are using is not on the list, but I'll talk to him

Comment: TLS can run on other ports.   Port 443 is the default.  If you are using a different port make sure it is doing TLS which is needed with HTTPS.

Comment: I talked to him, we are really using a different port and it is doing TLS... also, there is no conflict of applications on the port

Comment: I've seen issues recently where proxy was not relaying HTTP/HTTPS incorrectly.   the connection is not completing.  It looks like a TLS issue and may be a certificate issue or server doesn't support the encryption mode specified in the certificate.  Is hostsettings.json using HTTP or HTTPS?

Comment: I changed to https after reading your comment and the same exception appeared. Then I also changed the command on cmd to `dotnet MyAPI.dll --urls "https ://*:myportnumber` and the output was `crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[0]
      Unable to start Kestrel.
      System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint. No server certificate was specified, and the default developer certificate could not be found or is out of date.`. So I added `.UseKestrel()` to the webBuilder in `Program.cs` but the message persists.

Comment: TLS the client sends a request to server including the version of TLS.  Then the server returns a certificate block with the names of possible certificates.  The client then check the stores for one of the names and then uses the key in the certificate to encrypt messages.  The certificate has to be loaded on both client and server.  Using a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler you can see the version of TLS requested and check the certificate block to get the names of the certificate(s).  When a server starts it must be loaded with a default certificate.

Comment: See following for loading certificate into Kestrel : .https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-tutorial-dotnet-app-enable-https-endpoint

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! The enterprise hired an external expert to try and solve the problem... The API was stopped in the server's IIS, which I don't have access to. When I ran this command `dotnet MyAPI.dll --urls "http://*:myportnumber` it kinda forced to API to start, and that's why it worked only when it was running. Shame on us for not checking the server's IIS!

Comment: Sorry for wasting your time! ):

Comment: I said to check the event logs on server.  I didn't know you did have access the the event.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that... I can access the server, but not the IIS, so I couldn't check the IIS or the log